# How many white keys are between two keys?

Tags: algorithm

Let's take a look at these types:

```
public enum KeyTone : int
{
    C = 0, 
    Cs = 1, 
    D = 2, 
    Ds = 3, 
    E = 4, 
    F = 5, 
    Fs = 6, 
    G = 7, 
    Gs = 8, 
    A = 9, 
    As = 10, 
    H = 11
}

public class PianoKey
{
    public KeyTone Tone { get; set; }
    public int Octave { get; set; }
}
```

PianoKey represents a - well, you guessed - key on the piano. I need to check, how many white keys (e.g. these without "s" suffix) are between two specified white keys. The problem is that keyboard is not regular and there are no black keys between E and F and between H and C from the next octave.

There is an obvious brute-force solution - to jump to next white key until the requested second key is reached. But maybe there is some simpler way to calculate that?

Comment: I don't play piano. But I think there is a pattern: one group of 2 black keys, then one group of 3 black keys.

Comment: There are only 49 possible combinations of two white keys, so you could just hard-code the answers and save them in an array.  To take care of different octaves, just add 8.

Comment: How did you get the 49 combinations? (there are 52 white keys on the piano, BTW)

Comment: There are 7 white keys in one octave.  Given any two keys, you could have 7 ^ 2 = 49 combinations.

Comment: First of all, we have 6 octaves in the piano and 52 white keys. Secondly, distance between C4 and C6 equals to distance between C6 and C4, so we don't have to store both. If we take A0 (first key), we have 51 key distances to store. Then H0 - we have 50 key distances to store. So we have 51+50+...+3+2+1 = (51*52)/2 = 1326 combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, calculate the base tone for a given key (I assume all keys to be represented by their integers):

```
if tone <= KeyTone.E
    baseTone = tone / 2
else 
    baseTone = (tone + 1) / 2
```

Then, add the octave:

```
baseTone += Octave * 7
```

Then, you can find the difference in white keys by simple subtraction:

```
 diffInWhiteKeys = baseTone(key1) - baseTone(key2)
```

E.g. the difference between E2 and G3 is:

```
baseTone(E2) = 4 / 2 + 2 * 7 = 16
baseTone(G3) = (7 + 1) / 2 + 3 * 7 = 25
diff = 24 - 16 = 9
```

, which is exactly the number of white keys you have to advance from E2 to reach G3. If you're interested in the number of white keys between to keys, just subtract one.

Comment: `baseTone(C0) = 0`, `baseTone(Ds0) = 1`, white keys between `(1 - 0) - 1 = 0`, but should be 1.

Comment: @nwellnhof Problem statement was "how many white keys between two white keys". Black keys can be incorporated by appropriate rounding schemes.

Comment: Right, I didn't see that.

Answer (score 1):

Create two static arrays that map

- each black key to the next white key to the left or right,
- and each white key to itself,
- numbering white keys from 0 to 6.

```
static int[] whiteLeft  = new int[] {0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6};
static int[] whiteRight = new int[] {0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6};
```

Then the number of white keys between two keys can be computed as simple as

```
public static int WhiteKeysBetween(PianoKey left, PianoKey right)
{
    int wl = whiteLeft[(int)left.Tone];
    int wr = whiteRight[(int)right.Tone];

    return (right.Octave - left.Octave) * 7 + (wr - wl - 1);
}
```

**Edit:** This also works for white keys between any two keys (*white or black*). I didn't realize that the problem statement only asks for white keys between white keys.